# Sencha touch scrollable panel not work on android

Tags: sencha-touch, scrollbar, extjs

I built mobile web application with sencha touch 2.0
I have a regular panel object :

```
{
   html : "content",
   scrollable : true
}
```

When I use the scrollable option I have problem on android.
The scroll bar appears but all the content is no visible... just blank.

But the way , on iPhone I see the content and everything works.

Why its happened ? What I need to do to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Mention

**'fullscreen: true'**

While creating this panel

Thanks

Jaffer

Comment: it's not help , on android all the screen contents disappear.